# Cannot convert `object' expression to type `float' - HealthParam.SetValue (PlayerHealth.currentHealth);

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, fmod

I'm working on a demo audio project in Unity 5 and coming across some issues.  My goal is to assign the value of currentHealth (which is contained inside a separate "PlayerHealth" script) to a parameter in FMOD that modulates the music (makes it more intense) as the health of the player decreases.  I am not a programmer by any means, but have been forced to get my hands dirty to implement the music in Unity 5.

```
HealthParam.setValue (PlayerHealth.currentHealth);
```

This line of code is making Unity unhappy.  I've gathered it might have something to do with the difference between static and instance members, but again I'm not a programmer and really don't know how to delve into the weeds on this.

The errors are:

> "Argument `#1' cannot convert`object' expression to type `float'"
>
> "The best overloaded method match for
>   `FMOD.Studio.ParameterInstance.setValue(float)' has some invalid
>   arguments"
>
> "An object reference is required to access non-static member
>   `PlayerHealth.currentHealth'"

Here is the Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MusicManager : MonoBehaviour 
{


public int startingHealth = 100;                            
public int currentHealth;
public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
GameObject player; 

[FMODUnity.EventRef]
public string ScaryMusic = "event:/ZombunnyHorrorMusic";
FMOD.Studio.EventInstance MusicEv;
FMOD.Studio.ParameterInstance HealthParam;


void awake()
{
//      player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
//      playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
}

void Start () 
{
    MusicEv = FMODUnity.RuntimeManager.CreateInstance (ScaryMusic);
    MusicEv.getParameter ("Health", out HealthParam);
    MusicEv.start ();
}

void update()
{
//      currentHealth = Mathf.Abs (PlayerHealth.currentHealth);
    HealthParam.setValue (PlayerHealth.currentHealth);
}

void OnDestroy ()
{
    MusicEv.stop (FMOD.Studio.STOP_MODE.IMMEDIATE);
}


}
```

Comment: @Please post `HealthParam` class definition.

Comment: Can you share the code of `HealthParam` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `PlayerHealth` is a class and the instance variable `playerHealth` is of type `PlayerHealth`.

I guess what you really want is

```
HealthParam.setValue(playerHealth.currentHealth);
```

which would access the instance variable instead of the class. That's what the last error message suggests.

By using `PlayerHealth.currentHealth` you suggest that there is a class member (`static`) named `currentHealth`, which obviously does not exist. Using `playerHealth.currentHealth` you access the value of the current so called instance of `PlayerHealth`.

**Short "semi-developer" version of static vs. non-static**

Every member variable of a class can either be a class variable (declared `static`) or an instance variable (without `static`). A class variable can be accessed without having a current instance of the class (created with `new`). An instance variable (as the name already suggests) is only available if you have an instance of the class at hand.

Example:

```
public class StaticVSNonStatic
{
    public static int StaticValue;
    public int NonStaticValue;
}
```

The following works:

```
StaticVSNonStatic.StaticValue = 5;
```

The following doesn't:

```
StaticVSNonStatic.NonStaticValue = 5;
```

For the latter you need an instance of the `StaticVSNonStatic` class:

```
StaticVSNonStatic instance = new StaticVSNonStatic();
instance.NonStaticValue = 5;
```

Please note that class variables should really be an exception, as usually the point of having instances of a class is to have separate "records" that follow the same data model but contain different data.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  Technically, this is why the code was not compiling.  However, there was a bigger problem that was not allowing the code to function as I intended.  Even though changing "PlayerHealth" to "playerHealth" fixed the errors, the code was still not utilizing the correct value of "currentHealth".  Hence, the music was not changing in relation to the player's health.

Comment: ^The reason for this, and I am still baffled about this, is that there were TWO "PlayerHealth" scripts.  Because this was a tutorial project, the original developers included 2 copies of every script in the game.  Hence, when calling "PlayerHealth" in my MusicManager script, it would call the script that was not in use in the scene.  The version of "PlayerHealth" that was attached had a namespace in the code, and I simply had to include that namespace when calling the script.

Even though it was a simple solution, it was a real pain to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the error says it all. You're trying to access an instance member without providing an object reference in your line.

```
HealthParam.setValue (PlayerHealth.currentHealth);
```

I don't know what your PlayerHealth code looks like, but I think you need to change this to:

```
HealthParam.setValue (playerHealth.currentHealth);
```

Just make sure your *playerHealth* variable is properly initialized before using it (you have the initialization commented out in the *awake* method).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change your Update function to the following:

```
void update() {
    HealthParam.setValue (playerHealth.currentHealth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Questions: 
Are you trying  " HealthParam.setValue(**currentHealth**)" where "currentHealth" is an 'int' field of class "MusicManager" ?
  if not, does class "PlayerHealth" has a public field "currentHealth"? Can you show the APIs if class "PlayerHealth" ?
  if yes, see [how to convert int to float](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23d023de-37ac-4533-b0d6-0f069702ce31/how-to-convert-int-to-float?forum=csharpgeneral)
 for converting 'int' to 'float'

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but this should really be a comment. Please rephrase this to an answer instead of asking questions.